# Which plastic wrap is okay for oven use?

Tags: baking

On television I have seen cooks use plastic wrap, then foil over a pan of food that is going to be baked. I can see how this would stop the chemical reaction between certain foods and the aluminum and possibly form a tighter seal on the pan.

How do I know which plastic wrap is okay to use in the oven i.e. won't melt all over my bakeware and/or food?

- Do I look for a certain plastic formulation?
- Will the packaging tell me a certain wrap is okay at typical oven baking temperatures (300°F-425°F)?

Answer (score 2):

The plastic actually does not reach 300°F in the oven.

According to a [forum post at Cheftalk](http://www.cheftalk.com/t/60242/plastic-wrap-in-the-oven#post_308533), the dish beneath the plastic releases steam, which cools the saran wrap to 212° F, which is still below the melting point.

However, you should not just use saran wrap. Saran wrap easily shreds, and there are special foils for heating food which are usually refered to as reynolon. These are stronger and more resistant against releasing chemicals into the food. Check the forum thread above for more information.

Comment: What about the part that's touching the pan and not the steam?

Comment: @Cascabel Good question. I've seen it mentioned in the forum post, but I assume that if you use an oven-appropriate container, it should be relatively easy to remove it.

Comment: Touching liquid water will guarantee that it doesn't reach boiling point. Steam can get hotter than liquid water. There are plastic films designed for oven use.

Answer (score -1):

DO NOT PUT NAME BRAND GLAD CLINGWRAP IN THE OVEN!!!

Clingwrap melts below 200 degrees. Save yourself the frustration, and learn from my mistake. Be careful with information that you receive from the internet.