# How to know what temperature cling film is safe to heat to

Tags: food-safety

I've been looking up how to make donner kebab at home, and the [instructions I found](https://www.theguardian.com/lifeandstyle/gallery/2012/feb/08/how-to-make-a-doner-kebab) suggests to wrap the meat in cling film and boil it - I guess similar to a home made bain-marie.

I didn't realise you could boil/cook with cling film and so have researched more about it and found out that if the cling film is designed for food (and therefore not the shrink wrap they put over cardboard boxes) it is likely to be "safe".

The cling film I have states the following:

> ...is a professional grade film that is ideal for use on all foods, for wrapping or use in the microwave or freezer.

Naturally I'm concerned about putting cling film into hot water/an oven.

If it matters, the product I'm asking about is Kirkland Signature All Purpose Cling Film

My question is, is there any guidance on what is the maximum temperature the film can withstand? For them to claim it's microwave safe, is there a minimum temperature/length of time it must withstand to claim it's microwave safe? Or is it very much up to the manufacturer to provide this information and there is no guideline/specification.

The suggested duplciate only covers boiling water... cling film (I think) is likely to react differently to different types of heat (water, oven, microwave etc)

Comment: I don't know if it is PVC but many are.  The melting point of PCV is 100–260 °C.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polyvinyl_chloride   If it will take a microwave pretty safe bet it can be boiled.  I could not (easily) find the material for that wrap.

Comment: If it is bona fide professional grade it should explicitly state such temperatures. And melting points are not the only factor determining whether a plastic is food safe at a given temperature.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it safe to use plastic wrap in boiling water?](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/1717/is-it-safe-to-use-plastic-wrap-in-boiling-water)

Comment: Oily food in a microwave, btw, can develop hot spots on the surface that are likely to damage most plastics (unless it would be PTFE - not transparent, or kapton - not considered food safe, or specialty PET variants like Hostaphan ), especially when they are thin and offer little thermal buffer...

Comment: This is not a dupe for the reason specified. If anything, the cited dupe is a subset of this question !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It depends on the country since what is classed as safe differs although there are lots of common points.

My own summary from the below English, Irish and American food standards are

1. Unless a cling film is specifically marked as not safe for microwave use, it must be suitable for use in the microwave under EU law.
2. In general, cling film should not be used in an oven as it can melt and could contaminate the food.
3. Check with the manufacturer

> While the Food Standards Authority in the UK does not have specific recommendations about microwaving with cling film, the Irish and American equivalents do. The Food Safety Authority of Ireland and The United States Department of Agriculture both advise that cling film should not touch food during cooking.
>
> When using cling film, you can also check the packaging for any specific instructions, but interestingly you don’t have to choose cling film that is labelled ‘microwave safe’. Unless a cling film is specifically marked as not safe for microwave use, it must be suitable for use in the microwave under EU law.

[Source for above quote](http://www.bbc.co.uk/programmes/articles/5mKq06jg32zpzwBTR1sYQp8/is-it-safe-to-use-cling-film-in-the-microwave)

> Can cling film be used in an oven?
> In general, cling film should not be used in an oven as it can melt and could contaminate the food. However, there may be cling film available which can be used in an oven, so it is advisable to check the manufacturer’s instructions on the cling film before use.
>
> Can cling film be used in a microwave?
> Check the manufacturer’s instructions to see if it is safe for use in a microwave. If using in a microwave the cling film should not touch the food

[Source for above quote](https://www.fsai.ie/faqs/cling_film_safety.html%20)

And finally

> What containers and wraps are safe to use in the microwave oven?
> Only use cookware that is specially manufactured for use in the microwave oven. Glass, ceramic containers, and all plastics that are safe to use usually will be labeled for microwave oven use.
>
> SAFE TO USE:
> ... (content removed to keep it brief)
> Wax paper, parchment paper, heavy plastic wrap. Do not allow plastic wrap to touch food; vent it to allow a steam escape.
>
> NOT SAFE TO USE:
> ... (content removed to keep it brief)
> Food cooked in any container or packaging that has warped or melted during heating.

[Source for above quote](https://www.fsis.usda.gov/wps/portal/fsis/topics/food-safety-education/get-answers/food-safety-fact-sheets/appliances-and-thermometers/microwave-ovens-and-food-safety/ct_index/!ut/p/a1/jZFLU8IwFIV_TZdpUgpMcYedcXhIEVEp3TBpSNto8zAJVPn1BphxxAEl2eTxnZtzT2AGU5gJvGUltkwKXO_3WXeFZqgb9GI0mvaCOzRMXmbTcRyjaN5xwPIPIAmv1F8YffSffnTFAy09iSclzBS2FWCikDAtqQVYmIZqA9NCyjUwuKD2ExSYWGAqSq27wErVDAtCjYPXwFZUc8mpPag4I1o2eEuB3FJxJH5UgimxKybW9AMuYHbqEgVuDpNw3h6MkhBN27-BMzEegcs5uSDKWuaHP1v2RR5GrmNNC6qp9jfaHVfWqhsPeahpGj_PiU-kv3nzkNKy1JhzajyEtWWk3q86fPyOuq9l2NqpXXP79BiY5UxFHmIGMHtoElgJNoYCUjNRgoLV3KW7Twl8Z3POTCWNhemJCaj4c7q77w8Qe-CLyPS_AMKu3xw!/#11)

Related: [Which plastic wrap is okay for oven use?](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/67572/which-plastic-wrap-is-okay-for-oven-use)

Answer (score 2):

I saw cling film used by an English chef on an English television program. He wrapped whatever he was cooking (I forget) in cling film and cooked it in the oven. The brand was unspecified.

I normally use Glad Wrap. I contacted them via their Website and and asked what at temperature I could their product in the oven.
They replied with "Don't use our product in an oven. It is unsafe at any heated temperature."

Contact the manufacturer and ask.

Comment: Wow. I wonder who that chef was? Even if he was using a heat-safe brand (I've never heard of one), his viewers probably weren't.

Comment: Very related: https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/67572/which-plastic-wrap-is-okay-for-oven-use

Comment: The chef was Paul Hollywood.